# Input does not submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, http-post

I’m implementing the Stripe card API.

Card details are sent to Stripe and Stripe generates a token. When the form is submitted, the form is prevented from submitting with JavaScript (event.preventDefault()), a token is generated by Stripe, the value of a hidden input in the form is set to the token. This is confirmed by alerting the value of the element. The form is then successfully submitted with form.submit().

The only issue is… the hidden input does not get submitted, despite the value being set alongside the name attribute and the method being POST for the form.

I don’t understand this. Are there any known issues? I’ve tried with GET too, to ensure I could see it if it was submitted with the form (in the URL) and it wasn’t.

```
<form action="https://secure.inquaress.com/checkout/payment/charge" method="POST" id="payment-form" style="line-height: 30px;line-height: 3vmax;">
                    <input id="stripeToken" type="hidden" name="stripeToken" value="" />
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="card-element">
                          Credit or debit card
                        </label>
                        <div id="card-element">
                          <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                        </div>

                        <!-- Used to display Element errors. -->
                        <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                    </div>
                    <button id="card-payment-submit">Submit Payment</button>
                </form> 
                    <script>
                    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_0uejDjv1y2yiA5ODrlGIv0Nd');
                    var elements = stripe.elements();
                    var style = {
                      base: {
                        // Add your base input styles here. For example:
                        fontSize: '16px',
                        color: "#32325d",
                      }
                    };

                    // Create an instance of the card Element.
                    var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

                    // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
                    card.mount('#card-element');
                    card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
                      var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                      if (event.error) {
                        displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
                      } else {
                        displayError.textContent = '';
                      }
                    });

                    // Create a token or display an error when the form is submitted.

                    function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
                      // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
                      document.getElementById('stripeToken').value = token.id;
                      alert(document.getElementById('stripeToken').value);
                      // Submit the form
                      form.submit();
                    }

                    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
                    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                      event.preventDefault();

                      stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
                        if (result.error) {
                          // Inform the customer that there was an error.
                          var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                          errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
                        } else {
                          // Send the token to your server.
                          stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
                        }
                      });
                    });

                    </script>
```

Comment: Can you include the simplest HTML and JS code listing to reproduce your problem? It will make it a lot easier to help you if we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The input element is not inside the form.

Comment: @DominicTobias Are we not? I already have.

Comment: Sorry, thought I had copied over the code. The code is now there.

Comment: This is why I asked for code Igor, as you can see the input is inside the form tag.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? I’m stumped…

Answer (score 1):

<del>Ok, this one took me a little time. You're not submitting your form. You use a `<button id="card-payment-submit">Submit Payment</button>` but this button is not a `<input type="submit" />` and doesn't have any `click` listener on it. So no data sent, clicking the button does nothing. You never enter the `form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {` bit.</del>

Edit : I add a minimal example of your code in a working case (just copy/paste it in a `test.html` file), now to understand why it doesn't in your page...

```
<form action="https://secure.inquaress.com/checkout/payment/charge" method="GET" id="payment-form" style="line-height: 30px;line-height: 3vmax;">
                    <input id="stripeToken" type="hidden" name="stripeToken" value="test" />
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="card-element">
                          Credit or debit card
                        </label>
                        <div id="card-element">
                          <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                        </div>

                        <!-- Used to display Element errors. -->
                        <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                    </div>
                    <button id="card-payment-submit">Submit Payment</button>
                </form> 
                    <script>

                    // Create a token or display an error when the form is submitted.

                    function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
                      // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
                      document.getElementById('stripeToken').value = token;
                      alert(document.getElementById('stripeToken').value);
                      // Submit the form
                      form.submit();
                    }

                    var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
                    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                      event.preventDefault();

                          // Send the token to your server.
                          stripeTokenHandler('test2');
                    });

                    </script>
```

Comment: I had looked at that. I added the inline ‘onclick=“document.getElementById(‘payment-form’).submit()” and still resolved to the same issue. I will try changing <button> to input though why would one work and not the other?

Comment: Just tried. No change. Also, take note that the page redirects to that of the “action” attribute of the form, indicating the form has indeed submitted, but without the input.

Comment: `.submit()` and `<input type="submit" />` are the same, but you need at least one of the two to send the form. That was the immediate problem but maybe there's still something preventing your code to work. Try adding `<input type="text" name="test" value="test" />` in your form and change the action to a locale address like `/index.php` to test it.

Comment: the text input doesn’t submit either. But if you follow the JavaScript, it successfully and correctly alerts where the alert() is in the stripeTokenHandler() function and continues to submit the form and go to the action page, but without the inputs. My head hurts

Comment: You did say that the form was sent even without a `onclick` or a `<input type="submit" />`. If you put a `alert(form.length);` just before the `form.submit();` does it appear ? and does it return 1 ?

Comment: You’re welcome to view the page, but this is an online store so you would need to add one of the test products to your bag before you can access the checkout and fill out forms until you get to the “payment” page. You will not be charged (otherwise my bank balance would be in the negatives by now!) - these APIs are in sandbox modes.

Comment: It says 5 actually. 

Comment: Ah. The 5 inputs include the Stripe elements loaded by the JavaScript. Link to website: www.inquaress.com

Comment: Added a minimal example of working code. I saw your page but there's too much stuff to link. My advice would be to start from the working example and keep adding stuff until you pinpoint what is the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I had set the action link to /charge but I actually had to specify /charge/index.php for this to work.